# enable button with RxSwift logic

Tags: ios, iphone, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm new to `RxSwift` and want to achieve the following. I have a `email and password TextField`. When you've entered a text in both `textfields` a button should be enabled.

In my ViewController I do the following:

```
txtEmail.rx.text.asObservable()
  .bindTo(viewModel.email)
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

txtPassword.rx.text.asObservable()
  .bindTo(viewModel.password)
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

viewModel.buttonEnabled
  .bindTo(btnLogin.rx.isEnabled)
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

And here is my ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class LoginViewModel {

    let email = Variable<String?>("")
    let password = Variable<String?>("")

    var buttonEnabled: Observable<Bool>

    init() {

        var processedEmail: Observable<String>!
        var processedPassword: Observable<String>!

        processedEmail = email.asObservable().map(String.toLower as! (String?) -> String).map(String.trimWhiteSpace as! (String?) -> String)
        processedPassword = password.asObservable().map(String.toLower as! (String?) -> String).map(String.trimWhiteSpace as! (String?) -> String)

        let emailValid = processedEmail.asObservable().map(String.isNotEmpty)
        let passwordValid = processedPassword.asObservable().map(String.isNotEmpty)

        buttonEnabled = Observable.combineLatest(emailValid, passwordValid) {
            return $0 && $1
        }

    }

    func didTapLoginButton() {
        print("hello \(email.value)")
    }
}
```

For some reason the `init` method of my `viewmodel` never gets finished.
Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "never gets finished"?

Comment: @tomahh I get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on the init method

Comment: Are you sure `toLower` and `trimWhiteSpace` actually have `(String?) -> String` type? That's the only line I'd suspect could generate the crash.

Comment: That's probably the problem, but I don't know how I can solve it using proper RxSwift logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the definition of `processedEmail` and `processedPassword` are generating the crash preventing the view model init to complete.

More specifically, the `String.toLower` and `String.trimWhiteSpace` method probably have type `(String) -> String` but here they are force cast to `(String?) -> String`.

```
processedEmail = email.asObservable()
  .map { $0 ?? "" }
  .map(String.toLower)
  .map(String.trimWhiteSpace)

processedPassword = password.asObservable()
  .map { $0 ?? "" }
  .map(String.toLower)
  .map(String.trimWhiteSpace)
```

I've only added `.map { $0 ?? "" }`. Because the original observable has type `Observable<String?>` the map call will transform it to `Observable<String>` which will then be processable by `String.toLower` and `String.trimWhiteSpace`

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example of init and it seems working:

```
init() {
    let processedEmail = email.asObservable()
        .map { $0 ?? "" }
        .map { $0.lowercased() }
        .map { !$0.isEmpty }

    let processedPassword = password.asObservable()
        .map { $0 ?? "" }
        .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines) }
        .map { !$0.isEmpty }

    buttonEnabled = Observable.combineLatest(processedEmail, processedPassword) {
        return $0 && $1
    }
}
```